# How to import a python file which resides in outer directory

Tags: python

I have a constants file containing some keys and values for constants in my code.

```
hct/constants.py
```

and I am importing them in my utility which is in

```
hct/data_processors
```

by doing an import inside the utility

```
import constants
```

Upon executing I get an ImportError.

```
File "web_page_test_utils.py", line 7, in <module>
import constants
ImportError: No module named constants
```

How can I import a file that is from outer directory.

Comment: Have you looked at https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages?

Comment: yes I tried a relative import as from .. constants import constants. It too did not work.

Comment: What is the structure of your "package"? Do you have appropriate `__init__.py` files? What does *"did not work mean"* - difference error message? Same error message? Something else?

Comment: error said "ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package" . `__init__.py` is in the same folder as constants.py

Comment: And is there an `__init__.py` in `/data_processors`? Could you show the full structure in the question? A [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is always helpful.

Comment: The basic problem is that you haven't installed `hct`. Top level scripts are not part of packages and generally shouldn't use package relative imports. You can fiddle with `sys.path` to get around that or use `distutils` to package and install your stuff.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way:

```
import os
import sys

htc_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
if htc_path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(htc_path)

import constants
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, the only solution I've found is to append the parent directory (your outer directory) to the sys.path

```
import sys

sys.path.append('./..')
```

Otherwise I think you need to run your code from the parent directory (ie hct/file_in_which_you_do_your_imports.py) so to include the hct/constants.py and hct/data_processors/web_page_test_utils.py